# Where i should keep my libs for testing with mocha in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I need to test my nodejs module, which writes some data to output. I wrote DebugStream stream to collect output data to assert it later:

```
function DebugStream () {
  stream.Writable.call(this);
  this.data = '';
};
util.inherits(DebugStream, stream.Writable);

DebugStream.prototype._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  this.data += chunk;
  done();
}

DebugStream.prototype.getData = function () {
  return this.data;
}
```

I do not want to write this code in every test file. It would be nice to move it away somewhere, but i can't get how to organize it. I can't place it in test/ folder, because mocha will think that it's a test.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under tests you can create folders and node modules, so basically treat tests as a subproject in  a folder with all required modules and tools, check this as an example:

https://github.com/edsadr/change-api/tree/master/test